# Custom module data returning successfully but not displaying

Tags: node.js, module, return

I have a custom module in file `help.js`, the function name there is `getfriends(req,res,next,user)`. The user is whose friends I want to get.

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < docs.length; j++) {
    if (docs[j].user1 == users[i].username) {
      if (docs[j].user1 != req.body.user) {
        friends.push(users[i]);
      }
    } else if (docs[j].user2 == users[i].username) {
      if (docs[j].user2 != req.body.user) {
        friends.push(users[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  if (i == users.length-1) {
    console.log("friends",friends); //it displays my desired result and so I think the return is successfull
    return(friends);
  }
}
```

Now where I receive the data, I do this and data is not being displayed.

```
console.log(Help.getfriends(req,res,next,req.session.user));
```

I have tried doing :-

```
somevar = Help.getfriends(req,res,next,req.session.user);
console.log(somevar);
```

The module is being called, it is displaying perfect result. Please guide me how to get the data properly from the custom module.
Also, above I have done,

```
var Help = require('./help');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is asynchronous.
When you `console.log(...) <== there is no result yet.`
So i'ts expected that you `console.log undefined`.

More info about [nodejs asyncronous nature](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/).

Comment: yeah but I can't do the callback scene in here, I tried :-
    
    Help.getfriends(req,res,next,req.session.user,function(err,friends){
    console.log(friends);   //not printing anything
    )};

So what can I do to get data from a thing like this, tried promises same output i.e nothing??

Comment: You have to understand, that in most cases you use existing infrastructure, in others you create yours.